# Mean filter for smoothing images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I need to test some basic image processing techniques in Matlab. I need to test and compare especially two types of filters: mean filter and median filter.

To smooth image using median filtering, there is a great function `medfilt2` from image processing toolbox. Is there any similar function for mean filter? Or how to use the `filter2` function to create the mean filter?

One of the most important things for me is to have the possibility of setting radius of the filter. I.e. for median filter, if I want the [3 x 3] radius (mask), I just use

```
imSmoothed = medfilt2(img, [3 3]);
```

I would like to achieve something similar for mean filter.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
h = fspecial('average', n);
filter2(h, img);
```

See `doc fspecial`:
`h = fspecial('average', n)` returns an averaging filter. `n` is a 1-by-2 vector specifying the number of rows and columns in `h`.

Comment: Great, that's what I needed. And found some other interesting filters there, if I could I would accept this answer twice :D Many thanks!

Comment: You can review it here: http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/toolbox/images/enhan23b.html

Answer (score 9):

I see good answers have already been given, but I thought it might be nice to just give a way to perform mean filtering in MATLAB using no special functions or toolboxes. This is also very good for understanding exactly how the process works as you are required to explicitly set the  convolution kernel. The mean filter kernel is fortunately very easy:

```
I = imread(...)
kernel = ones(3, 3) / 9; % 3x3 mean kernel
J = conv2(I, kernel, 'same'); % Convolve keeping size of I
```

Note that for colour images you would have to apply this to each of the channels in the image.

Comment: Thanks. But in the imfilter documentation it is said that it uses conv2 in most of the cases. So reading the doc brought me to the same conclusions. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

```
I = imread('peppers.png');
H = fspecial('average', [5 5]);
I = imfilter(I, H);
imshow(I)
```

Note that filters can be applied to intensity images (2D matrices) using `filter2`, while on multi-dimensional images (RGB images or 3D matrices) `imfilter` is used.

Also on Intel processors, `imfilter` can use the Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (IPP) library to accelerate execution.

Comment: You can't design a kernel for median filtering because it is a non-linear convolution: for each NxN neighborhood the calculations involve more than just products and sums.

Comment: Which is benefit of average kernel in image segmentation? I read some paper they said that average kernel and gaussian kernel are similar. And average kernel will run faster than gaussian kernel by 1D convolution,Right?

Comment: Both have the effect of *blurring* an image, difference is in how they incorporate nearby pixels. An average kernel takes the average value of pixels in the neighborhood, with all pixels given equal weight. A Gaussian kernel will take a weighted average such that it gives more weight to pixels in the middle of the neighborhood and less weight as you move away from the center (the weights are derived from the normal distribution "bell-shaped curve").. Compare the output of `fspecial('average', [7 7])` against `fspecial('gaussian', [7 7], 1.1)` (both return a normalized kernel that sums to `1`)

Comment: Yes, Right. I read in the book "Digital Image Processing"-R.C. Gonzales. He said that average kernel gives large error than gaussian kernel with small kernel size. Both of them are lower filter. So, Why they use average kernel instead of gaussian kernel?

Comment: @user8264: I don't have access to the book right now, but usually the Gaussian kernel provides a gentler smoothing effect and tends to preserve the edges better than a mean-filter of the same size. Think of the [frequency response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_response) of the lowpass filter in both cases... Here is a page with a good explanation: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/gsmooth.htm

Comment: Here is an example showing the difference of applying the two filters: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GYIlj.png

Comment: I think oter different between gaussian and mean that is mean kernel gives equally weighted values for its neighbor, while gaussian is differnent weighted values. Compare with ball kernel (all weighted values is 1), Do you think which is better for image denoising?

Answer (score 2):

and the convolution is defined through a multiplication in transform domain:

```
conv2(x,y) = fftshift(ifft2(fft2(x).*fft2(y)))
```

if one channel is considered... for more channels this has to be done every channel

Answer (score 0):

```
f=imread(...);

h=fspecial('average', [3 3]);
g= imfilter(f, h);
imshow(g);
```

Comment: in what way is this answer different than [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1738390/1714410)?