# Fill NaNs in a non-square region

Tags: matlab, nan

I am working with some reconstructed images that are not square, and I need to compare them to my "ideal image". The thing is that as the reconstructed images are obtained with different methods, the "shape" of the image is not constant and I need to fill those NaNs somehow.

Well, as its not so easy to explain, lets illustrate with an example:

```
Orig_image=[ NaN NaN 1 NaN NaN
             NaN 4   2 6   NaN
             6   3   2 2   2
             NaN 3   4 1   NaN
             NaN NaN 5 NaN NaN];

Rec_image=[ NaN NaN  1 NaN NaN
            NaN NaN  2  3  NaN
            6    3   2  2    2
            NaN  3   2  1   NaN
            NaN  NaN 5 NaN NaN];

isnan(Orig_image)~=isnan(Rec_image)

ans=[ 0 0 0 0 0
      0 1 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0]
```

You can see that the element (2,2) is NaN in Rec_image. 
I would like to fill that NaN with an interpolated value of its neighbours, but dont know how to approach the problem.

Additional information:
 my images are in general 100x100 and the amount of not-matching nans around 20. However there its possible that the not-matching NaNs in an specific area is "bigger" (i.e. 4x4 square) so there are NaNs that have not any numerical neighbours.

Comment: Have you already seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3632014/1136458
Even if the question is about 1d array some answers consider also the 2d case

Comment: @lib Let me check that...

Comment: @lib it works like charm. Post your it as an answer (I did saw that post before, but I thought it was not going to work). Plus the answer is working for me is not the "accepted answer" in the other post.

Comment: ok nice, I've never tried the method before neither :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in [MATLAB: Using interpolation to replace missing values (NaN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628957/matlab-using-interpolation-to-replace-missing-values-nan/3632014#3632014) , on matlabcentral there is a tool called [inpaint_nans](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551-inpaint-nans), which replaces nan elements in 1-d or 2-d matrices by interpolation

Comment: And extrapolation! thats the part that was usefull for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest thing is to use a filter kernel which is larger than your NaN blocks.  If you apply the filter in the usual order (simply iterating over the dimensions of the image) you may not get the best results.

Start with this discussion for creating/applying averaging filters of arbitrary size:
[Mean filter for smoothing images in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737960/mean-filter-for-smoothing-images-in-matlab)

Then I would order the non-matching NaNs by how many non-NaN neighbors each has.  Apply the filter to each of those points, starting with those that have the least NaN neighbor points and ending with those that have the most.

Of course, you may want something other than a mean filter.  Use a filter kernel that's appropriate for your data (e.g. something that interpolates well).

Comment: Thanks! Even if your answer is pretty good I solved it using the inpaint_nans function of the post suggested.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Please post your solution

Comment: @Dan I am waiting for @ lib to do it, as he suggested me the solution, he should get credit.